# Question about returning an unique_ptr from a function

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

As per the [document](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0527r1.html), which says that

> We already have implicit moves for local values and function
> parameters in a return statement. The following code compiles just
> fine:
>
> ```
> std::unique_ptr<T> f(std::unique_ptr<T> ptr) {
>     return ptr;
> }
> ```
>
> However, the following code does not compile
>
> ```
> std::unique_ptr<T> f(std::unique_ptr<T> && ptr) {
>     return ptr;
> }
> ```
>
> Instead, you must type
>
> ```
> std::unique_ptr<T> f(std::unique_ptr<T> && ptr) {
>     return std::move(ptr);
> }
> ```

Here are my questions:

1.There is no copy ctor for `std::unique_ptr<T>` indeed, there should not a function could accept a parameter declared as `std::unique_ptr<T>`. See this [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/nqqv4n6q5), it does not compile.

```
#include <memory>

class FooImage{};

std::unique_ptr<FooImage> FoolFunc(std::unique_ptr<FooImage> foo)
{
    return foo;
}

int main()
{

    std::unique_ptr<FooImage> uniq_ptr(new FooImage);

    FoolFunc(uniq_ptr);
}
```

2.why

```
std::unique_ptr<T> f(std::unique_ptr<T> && ptr) {
    return ptr;
}
```

does not compile?

Could somebody shed some light on this matter?

Comment: @Michael Chourdakis Any reference? And why this [code snippet](https://godbolt.org/z/nqqv4n6q5) does not compile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1.There is no copy ctor for `std::unique_ptr<T>` indeed, there should not a function could accept a parameter declared as
> `std::unique_ptr<T>`.

In fact, this is ok as long as you *move* the original `std::unique_ptr` to this local parameter

```
FoolFunc(std::move(uniq_ptr)); // ok
FoolFunc(std::unique_ptr<FooImage>{new FooImage}); // also ok
```

> 2.why
>
> `std::unique_ptr<T> f(std::unique_ptr<T> && ptr) { return ptr; }`
>
> does not compile?

Although the type of `ptr` is an rvalue reference, it is itself an *lvalue*, so `return ptr` will call the copy ctor, you need to use `std::move` to cast `ptr` to an rvalue again

```
std::unique_ptr<T> f(std::unique_ptr<T> && ptr) { 
    return std::move(ptr); 
}
```